# How can I play with local teammate on PC?

Tags: pc, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014

Is there a way to play **Two Headed gigant** in Magic 2014 with a **local teammate** against remote opponents?

We are sitting in front of a PC with my friend and we would like to play with guys from the internet. When I create a game and select "Play with local teammate" I get:

"magic 2014 at least one controller is required"

What does it mean? Is that even possible on PC? Do I need to connect another mouse or something?

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate controller for the other player, the safest bet would be a actual controller like a Xbox 360 controller. You then need to configure this correctly in the game settings before hosting.